# Colimit of the sequence $X\to FX\to FFX\to\dots$

Tags: category-theory

I'm interested in saying something about the colimit
$$
T_F(X):=\varinjlim\Big(X\to FX\to FFX\to\dots\Big)
$$
taken starting from a pointed endofunctor $F\colon\cal C\to C$; fiddling a little with adjointness, this amounts to a colimit $\mathbb N\to [\cal C,C]$, which exists as soon as $\cal C$ is cocomplete.

It seems to me that the functor $T_F\colon \cal C\to C$ sending $A$ into $\varinjlim{}_n \;F^nA$ is again pointed, and it admits a canonical arrow $T_F\to T_FT_F$ (deduced from UP of colimit and the arrow $\varinjlim \circ F\to F\circ \varinjlim$). I would have expected either a copointed functor with something to be proved to be a comultiplication, or a pointed functor with a would-be multiplication. But this?

I do believe this problem is elementary, but in general one can hardly say anything. Nevertheless I'd like to see something explicit: feel free to give me additional (non-too-much-trivial) assumptions.

A lazy computation:
$$\begin{align*}T_FT_F(X) &= \Big(\varinjlim_m F^m\Big)\Big(\varinjlim_n F^n\Big)X\\&\cong \varinjlim_m F^m\Big( \varinjlim_n (F^n X)\Big)\\&\cong \varinjlim_m\Big(F^m \varinjlim_n (F^n X)\Big) \\& \leftarrow \varinjlim_m\varinjlim_nF^mF^nX\\&\cong \varinjlim_{(m,n)} F^{m+n}X \cong \varinjlim_{(n,n)} F^{n+n}X\\&\cong \varinjlim_n F^{2n}X \cong T_FX\end{align*}$$
where the last isomorphisms hold since $\omega$ is a filtered category, hence sifted, hence a series of finality arguments help to conclude.

Comment: I don't know, in fact, I'm stuck there since yesterday and can't see why. Maybe I'm secretly doing a different colimit? Is a lazy-computation too lazy to be right? In the end, am I claiming something false?

Comment: Removed comment? anyway I added the details of the lazy computation giving an arrow $T_FX\to T_FT_FX$. Good luck to those who want to prove or disprove it's a comultiplication, or something similar!

Comment: I don't really see what you want to say, but down this road lies the free monad associated to $F$ given some accessibility and presentability assumptions on $F$ and $\mathcal C$ respectively; you might be interested in http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transfinite+construction+of+free+algebras

Comment: A-ha! I knew that the "and so on" paper by Kelly was linked to this. Amazing.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Choose one among these :) What is the meaning of that colimit in general? How can one compute it? Does it have some distinguishing properties? If the endofunctor is "nice" is $T_F$ "nice" too? Is $F\mapsto T_F$ a "nice" endofunctor of $[\cal C,C]$?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that your lazy computation is a little too lazy.  Try writing down the actual maps in these colimiting diagrams, and I think you'll see that you need $F$ to be *well* pointed.

In that case, if you assume additionally that $F$ preserves sequential colimits, so that your map is an isomorphism, then $T_F$ is the free monad generated by $F$, which is idempotent (i.e. its multiplication transformation is an isomorphism) since $F$ is well-pointed.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I suspected you need well-pointedness of $F$ to ensure there's no possible choice between all the various $F^i\eta F^{n-i}$. I suspect you're here after having read my [comment](http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/6028/transfinite-constructions-of-free-algebras/#Item_5) on the nforum, so let me ask you: what about $T_{2,F}=T_{T_F}$ and its iterates $T_{n, F}:=T_{T_{n-1, F}}$?

Comment: If a well-pointed endofunctor is already monad, then it is its own free monad.  In other words, idempotent monads are a reflective subcategory of well-pointed endofunctors.  Thus, if $F$ is well-pointed, $T_{T_F} = T_F$.